# Restrict google app engine api by bundle identifier iOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, bundle-identifier

I am using google app engine to talk to my iOS app. Is there a way to restrict the api access using the app bundle identifier so that no other apps can access the api?

Answer (score 0):

How does your app talk to GAE? This is possible with [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/auth).